# Color rows when "group by" sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I need some help. I'm trying to set color when group by in a sharepoint list.

I'm using the following code

SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

```
   var statusColors =  {
      'Liberada' : '#FFF1AD',  
      'Cancelada' : '#FFD800',
      'Créditos' : '#01DF3A' 
   };

   var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
   for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
   {
      var status = rows[i]["Status"];
      var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
      var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
      row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
   }
 }
```

});

});

Can someone give a hint?

Comment: Ok so, if I understand correctly, you have a Sharepoint custom list with a view grouped by a status field and you want to add a background color to some (or all) status. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes! Thats what I want to do!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in my local Sharepoint 2013 environment, when I create a view with a group by, Sharepoint add a CSS class named « ms-gb » on the table cell that contains the group name.

Knowing this, a solution would be to edit the page of the view.

Then you can add to the page a Script Editor Webpart.

Inside this Script Editor Webpart you can add some JavaScript code to add the background-color.

Something like this for example :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var statusNames = ['Liberada', 'Cancelada', 'Créditos'];
    var statusColors = {
      'Liberada' : '#FFF1AD',  
      'Cancelada' : '#FFD800',
      'Créditos' : '#01DF3A' 
    };
    $('td.ms-gb').each(function(){
        for (var x=0;x<statusNames.length;x++) {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf(statusNames[x]) > -1) {
                $(this).css('background-color',statusColors[statusNames[x]]);
            }
        }       
    });
});
</script>
```

If you try this script and you don't already have a reference to JQuery in your masterpage or page layout, you will need to add one inside the script editor webpart.

You can download a local copy of JQuery or use one hosted like :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this help.